# How to get last matching value using multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do a lookup based on 2 criteria to match on another sheet and return a value from the last match that it finds.

I've been able to get this logic working with a single criteria:

`=INDEX('Rank History'!B:E, MAX(filter(ROW('Rank History'!E:E), 'Rank History'!E:E=C3)),3)`

and I've been able to do it with multiple criteria:

`=INDEX('Rank History'!D:D, MATCH(1, (B3='Rank History'!B:B) * (C3='Rank History'!E:E), 0))`

How do I tie these two approaches together?

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet with your expected output? It is quite challenging to analyze the formula without a sample data. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: What do you mean by tie those two? The multiple criteria approach should also work with single criteria right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=INDEX('Rank History'!D:D, MATCH(2, 1 / ((B3='Rank History'!B:B) * (C3='Rank History'!E:E))))
```